# Valor undefined en return pero correcto en la función

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ante todo gracias a esta comunidad. Esta es mi primera consulta.

Tengo una función en javascript que hace una llamada mediante ajax a un script.
Dentro de esta función, el valor de las variables es correcto. Esta es la función (destaco que es igual a otras tantas llamadas con diferentes parámetros "data":

```js
function existe_dni(dni_a_verificar)
{
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'validacion.php',
                data:'dni_existe='+dni_a_verificar,
                success:function(html){
                        var validacion = $.parseJSON(html);
                        console.log("DNI: " + dni_a_verificar + " (" + typeof(dni_a_verificar) + ")");
                        console.log("Validacion: " + validacion + " (" + typeof(validacion) + ")");
                        console.log("");
                        return validacion;
                },
                error:function(jqxhr, status, exception){
                        return -1;
                }
        });
}
```

Y esta es la función que recibe el return anterior. Acá, la variable existe_el_dni siempre y en todo momento tiene el valor undefined:

```js
else {
                var existe_el_dni = existe_dni(dni);
                console.log("(if) DNI: " + dni + " (" + typeof(dni) + ")");
                console.log("(if) Existe? " + existe_el_dni);
                if (existe_el_dni == -1)
                {
                        dni_ctl.style.borderColor = "red";
                        errores_personal_cnt++;
                        errores_personal += "\t- el D.N.I. ya existe\n";
                }
        }
```

Realmente no sé qué es lo que no está funcionando, ya que como dije, esta función a otras tantas. Los console.log de la primera y segunda función muestran los valores correctos para la variable dni.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres usar los datos de la llamada de `ajax` deberás hacerlo con `Promise` en vez de la clásica `success/error`.

Y es que `ajax` devuelve una `Promise` que podrás esperar a que se resuelva y propagar.

```
function ajaxCall(dni_a_verificar)
{
    return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'validacion.php',
            data: 'dni_existe=' + dni_a_verificar
    });
}
```

Aquí se hace la llamada a `ajax`. Sin las propiedades `success` ni `error`, ya que las respuestas las esperaremos des de fuera.

```
function existe_dni(dni_a_verificar) {
    return ajaxCall(dni_a_verificar)
            .then(html => {
                var validacion = $.parseJSON(html);
                console.log("DNI: " + dni_a_verificar + " (" + typeof(dni_a_verificar) + ")");
                console.log("Validacion: " + validacion + " (" + typeof(validacion) + ")");
                console.log("");
                return validacion;
            })
            .catch(e => e);
}
```

Esta función llama a la anterior `ajaxCall`. Dentro de la función `then` estará la respuesta sin errores. El `catch` se invocará en caso que la llamada haya tenido algún tipo de error.
Esta función, `existe_dni` también devolverá una `Promise`. El resultado de esta será la variable `validacion` en caso de que la llamada `ajax` haya ido bien. En caso de error, sólo eleva la excepción hacia arriba.

Por último,

```
// ...
else {
    existe_dni(dni)
        .then(existe_el_dni => {
            console.log("(if) DNI: " + dni + " (" + typeof(dni) + ")");
            console.log("(if) Existe? " + existe_el_dni);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
            dni_ctl.style.borderColor = "red";
            errores_personal_cnt++;
            errores_personal += "\t- el D.N.I. ya existe\n";
        })
}
```

Aquí, de nuevo, llamaremos a `existe_dni` pero nos suscribiremos a la respuesta. La respuesta, obviamente será la variable `validación` en caso de que haya ido bien, y el error lo obtendremos dentro de la función `catch`.

Esto de puede refactorizar de mil formas más elegantes. Pero creo que esta, para empezar, es una forma fácil de entenderlo.

---

**Edit**
Con uso de `async/await` quedaría así.

```
async function existe_dni(dni_a_verificar)
{
    try {
        const html = await $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'validacion.php',
            data: 'dni_existe=' + dni_a_verificar
        });

        var validacion = $.parseJSON(html);
        console.log("DNI: " + dni_a_verificar + " (" + typeof(dni_a_verificar) + ")");
        console.log("Validacion: " + validacion + " (" + typeof(validacion) + ")");
        console.log("");
        return validacion;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

La llamada a `existe_dni` quedaría igual, con los métodos `then` y `catch`.

---

**Edit II**

> ¿Por qué otras llamadas a `ajax` funcionan y esta en concreto no lo hacía?

La sutil diferencia está en cómo tratas la respuesta y qué haces con ella. Supongamos el siguiente caso.

```
const ajaxCall = data => {
    $.ajax({
        type: `POST`,
        url: `http://example.com`,
        data,
        success: console.log,
        error: console.error
    });
}
```

Esta llamada hace una *request* por `ajax` y lo único que hace es imprimir la respuesta una vez la obtiene, o imprime el error, si hubo.
Si llamamos a esta función

```
ajaxCall(`some data`);
```

Imprime el resultado de la petición un tiempo después. Supongamos que el resultado es el siguiente

> AJAX result

¿Qué pasa si esperamos que nos devuelva algo?

```
const r = ajaxCall(`some data`);
console.log(r);

const r = ajaxCall(`some data`);
console.log(r);

// undefined
// AJAX result
```

La función retorna `undefined` (bueno, no es nada extraño porque no tenemos ningún `return` en la función `ajaxCall`). Pero vemos que primero ha retornado el `undefined` y después se ha llamado al `console.log` con la respuesta.

Vamos a poner un `return` a la función una vez tenemos los datos.

```
const ajaxCall = data => {
    $.ajax({
        type: `POST`,
        url: `http://example.com`,
        data,
        success: response => {
            return response;
        },
        error: console.error
    });
}

const r = ajaxCall(`some data`);
console.log(r);

// undefined
```

Y devuelve exactamente lo mismo, un `undefined`.

La propiedad `success` del objeto que le pasamos como argumento a la función `ajax` es una función, una *callback*. Esta función se ejecutará una vez `ajax` haya acabado con su trabajo.
Importante, de nuevo, **es una función**. Por lo que el `return` dentro de esta función afecta a ésta misma, no a la función `ajaxCall`.
La función `ajaxCall` **no** tiene ningún `return` explícito.

Con el siguiente ejemplo,

```
const fn = () => {
    const innerFn = n => {
        return n * 2;
    }

    const r = innerFn(3);
    return r * 2;
}

const r = fn();
console.log(r); // 12
```

... se obvia esto. El `return` dentro de `innerFn` afecta a `innerFn`, no a `fn`.

Cuando una función no tiene un `return`, Javascript lo interpreta como un `return undefined;` implícito.

```
const fn1 = () => {
    console.log(`Calling fn ...`);
    return;
}

const fn2 = () => {
    console.log(`Calling fn ...`);
}
```

`fn1` y `fn2` son exactamente iguales.

Resumiendo, ¿por qué es diferente una llamada a `ajax` de otra?
Va a depender de si esa función devuelve o no valores. Si todo lo que hace con la respuesta de `ajax` se hace en la misma `success`, no hace falta implementar ningún patrón de `Promise` (aunque implíticamente `ajax` sí lo hace por dentro).
Si necesitas que esa función devuelva algo, como era tu caso, deberás implementar las `Promise` para que des de fuera puedas esperar también a esa respuesta.

---

Para que no quede nada sin atar, para emular las llamadas `ajax` he usado lo siguiente.

```
const delay = millis => 
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, millis);
    });

const ajax = async ({ type, url, data, success, error }) => {
    try {
        await delay(1000);
        success(`AJAX result`);
    } catch (e) {
        error(e);
    }
}

const $ = { ajax };
```

---

Doy por respondida la pregunta. Si tienes otro tipo de dudas o errores, te sugiero que escribas otra pregunta diferente.
También te animo a leer la documentación y algunos artículos interesantes sobre la asincronicidad en Javascript.

- [Documentación `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)
- [Diferencias entre *callback* y `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)
- Un vídeo estupendo sobre la [asincronía en Javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrNQS8J67zc). La *call stack* y el *event loop*.
- El [mejor libro de Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491904224) que he tenido el gusto de leer.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Siempre das admirables respuestas.

Comment: ¡Gracias, @Riven!

Comment: Qué si sirve?? jaja! Fue una excelente explicación. Y con lujo de detalles. Voy a empezar a implementarla ahora mismo. Sin embargo, me queda la duda de por qué llamadas iguales funcionan bien y esta no. Desde ya aclaro que JS no es mucho lo mío, sé lo básico no mas. Tengo la pagina con el formulario y le añadí el JS para la usabilidad. Las funciones de validación las tengo en PHP entonces puse un archivo en el medio, validacion.php que responde al JS llamando a las funciones de validación de PHP. Quiero decir que tengo un montón de campos diversos que se validan de la misma forma.

Comment: Me gustaría entender por qué esta llamada en particular no funciona ya que el proyecto recién esta comenzando y hacer estas modificaciones en el futuro sería un dolor de cabeza.

Comment: Por favor, estoy siguiendo la conversación porque pedí mas explicaciones.Y esas explicaciones surgieron de la respuesta. Cuando tenga satisfecha la duda, elegiré y señalaré la respuesta mas adecuada a mi criterio. Gracias.

Comment: @julio está bien que sigas la conversación si necesitas aclaraciones, pero por favor hazlo en los comentarios de la respuesta. De ese modo el usuario que te respondió recibirá una notificación (si pones una respuesta aparte, no se da cuenta). Además que es cómo funciona Stack Overflow: un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde hay un lugar para la pregunta y otro para las respuestas. No es un foro donde se van publicando más y más respuestas extendiendo el asunto. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla)

Comment: Hola, @julio. En la respuesta tienes una explicación un poco más extensa a tu duda. Como puse, si sigues teniendo dudas te sugiero que hagas otra pregunta diferente con dudas más concretas. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @VRoxa, Si, lo estuve leyendo. La verdad te pasaste con la respuesta. Voy a publicar una nueva pregunta. Gracias!!