# Syntax Error en llamada AJAX con Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promesas

Esta pregunta deriva de mi anterior [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355998/valor-undefined-en-return-pero-correcto-en-la-funci%C3%B3n/356006?noredirect=1#356006)

Recibo errores de sintaxis (tokens inesperados, catch no es una función).

Así llamo a jQuery:

```html
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Y así he modificado las funciones involucradas:

```js
function ajaxCall(tipo, url, data)
{
        return $.ajax({
            type: tipo,
            url: url,
            data: data
        });
}
```

En esta función, recibo los errores de unexpected token en:
 - el `>` de `.then(html =>`
 - el `)` de cierre del `.then`
 - el `>` de `.catch(e => e`

```js
function existe_dni(dni_a_verificar) {
        return ajaxCall('POST', 'validacion.php', 'dni_existe='+dni_a_verificar)
                .then(html => {
                        var validacion = $.parseJSON(html);
                        console.log("DNI: " + dni_a_verificar + " (" + typeof(dni_a_verificar) + ")");
                        console.log("Validacion: " + validacion + " (" + typeof(validacion) + ")");
                        console.log("");
                        return validacion;
                    })
                .catch(e => e);
        }
```

Y en esta llamada a `existe_dni()`, idem en:
 - el `>` de `.then(existe_el_dni => {`
 - el `)` anterior al `.catch`
 - el `>` del `.catch`
 - el `)`del cierre del `.catch`

```js
 existe_dni(dni)
                        .then(existe_el_dni => {
                                console.log("(if) DNI: " + dni + " (" + typeof(dni) + ")");
                                console.log("(if) Existe? " + existe_el_dni);
                        })
                        .catch(e => {
                                console.error(e);
                                dni_ctl.style.borderColor = "red";
                                errores_personal_cnt++;
                                errores_personal += "\t- el D.N.I. ya existe\n";
                        })
```

Reitero que no es mi fuerte JS.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bueno, fue un "error" mío. Creo que *jQuery* no funciona con la sintaxis de *JS es6*... Aunque, a día de hoy ya no hay razones para usar *jQuery*. En cualquier caso, debes formatear el código a *es3*. Principalmente, dejar de usar las *arrow functions* (*lamdas*) para usar la sintaxis de *function*.

Comment: En realidad, yo no había indicado en la pregunta anterior el header html. Voy a seguir leyendo la documentación que me pasaste.

Comment: No hace falta. Va implícito en el hecho de que usaras `ajax`, c:

Comment: PD: Si, como comentabas, es un proyecto que estás justo empezando ahora, te recomiendo muchísimo que uses [*axios*](https://github.com/axios/axios). Es una librería más moderna y eficaz en cuando a protocolo HTTP.

Comment: Estaba mirando las librerías y esa es una de las que había visto. Voy a seguir tu consejo y reescribir todo con esta librería.

Comment: AJAX es una tecnologia bastante antigua,  por consiguiente ajax no usa promises si no callbacks para dar un resultado,  pero hay una forma facil de promisificar ajax para que puedas usarlo asi.

Comment: Hola @Riven. Si, estoy haciendolo con axios. Ya que estamos, cómo recibe PHP la información que le paso por post desde axios?

Comment: Ya lo empiezo a ver: con json_decode y file_get_contents