# Promise siempre en estado "pending"

Tags: javascript, post, axios, undefined

Acá vengo con otra consulta, que viene de [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355998/valor-undefined-en-return-pero-correcto-en-la-funci%C3%B3n) y de [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356196/syntax-error-en-llamada-ajax-con-promise).

Finalmente, armé esto:

```js
function axiosCallPost(url, datastr)
{
        var resultado = "vacio, nada, cero";
        axios.post(url, {
                data:datastr
                , responseType:'text'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
//                        console.log("ok -> " + response.data);
//                        console.log(response);
                        resultado = response.data;
        })
        /*
         * para simplificarme la vida, responde 'errorr'
         * pero debería devolver algo mas
         */
        .catch(function(response) {
//                        console.log("ko -> " + response);
                        resultado = 'errorr';
        });
        return resultado;
}

async function validar_dni(dni_a_validar, url, secc)
{
        var datastr = 'secc=' + secc + '&dni=' + dni_a_validar;
//        console.log("datastr: " + datastr);
        var respuesta = await axiosCallPost(url, datastr);
        return respuesta;
}

var validacion_dni = validar_dni(dni, url_validacion, "dni");
```

Y no hay forma de que devuelva response.data. Dentro de la llamada a `axios.post`, el resultado es correcto. Fuera es siempre `undefined`.

Gracias otra vez!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript es didferente a los otros lenguajes como `java`, `c++`, o `C#` :3 es de hilo unico, por lo que no se puede dar el lujo de bloquear el hilo. Lo que esta pasando en tu codigo es mas o menos lo siguiente

```
function axiosCallPost(url, datastr)
{
        // javascript crea una variable string.
        var resultado = "vacio, nada, cero";
        // el http request es un metodo asyncrono
        // se hace un http request, pero como es async lo manda al lugar magico, pero JS no espera, asi que se va a la siguiente instruccion
        axios.post(url, {
                data:datastr
                , responseType:'text'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
//                        console.log("ok -> " + response.data);
//                        console.log(response);
                        resultado = response.data;
        })
        /*
         * para simplificarme la vida, responde 'errorr'
         * pero debería devolver algo mas
         */
        .catch(function(response) {
//                        console.log("ko -> " + response);
                        resultado = 'errorr';
        });

        // aun no se a resuelto la promesa, pero encontro un reeturn retorna resultado,pero la promesa se quedo pending </3
        return resultado;
}


async function validar_dni(dni_a_validar, url, secc)
{
        var datastr = 'secc=' + secc + '&dni=' + dni_a_validar;
//        console.log("datastr: " + datastr);
        var respuesta = await axiosCallPost(url, datastr);
        return respuesta;
}

var validacion_dni = validar_dni(dni, url_validacion, "dni");
```

lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente.

```
/**
 * Ejecuta http request.
 *
 * @param {string} url - definicion de lo que es.
 * @param {string} datastr - definicion de lo que es.
 * @returns resultado que retorna
 */
function axiosCallPost (url, datastr) {
   return axios.post(url, data: datastr)
   .then(response => response.data);
}

async function otraFuncion (dni_a_validar, url, secc) {
 const datastr..........
}
```

`datastr` pare que son `query params` pero en la funcion que hace el request, lo tienes en el body.

para que `axiosCallPost` funcione lo debes de cambiar

```
// en javascript por buena practica se utiliza: camelCase o snake_case, pero nada mas uno. No se mesclan y por lo general siempre es camelCase
async function otraFuncion (dniAValidar, url, secc) {
 const datastr = JSON.stringify({ dniAValidar, secc });

 const res = await axiosCallPost(url, datastr);
}
```

si lo que quieres es que `validarDni` funcione debes de cambiarla asi

```
 function axiosCallPost (url) {
   return axios.get(url).then(...)
 }


async function validarDni (dniAValidar, url, secc) {
  const res = await axiosCallPost(`${url}?dniAValidar=${dniAValidar}&secc={secc}`).then(...)
}
```

Comment: Lo que no comprendo es, si en `axiosCallPost()` saco el último `return` y pongo los correspondientes en `then` y `catch`, por qué `response.data` no devuelve lo que debería si se supone que espera a que se resuelva?