# AXIOS: valor correcto en .then, incorrecto afuera del .then

Tags: javascript, post, axios, async

Esta pregunta deriva de [acà](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355998/valor-undefined-en-return-pero-correcto-en-la-funci%C3%B3n), [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356196/syntax-error-en-llamada-ajax-con-promise) y [acà](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356533/promise-siempre-en-estado-pending/356559#356559) (pero no afecta a esta pregunta que hago ahora).

Esta función hace la llamada asíncrona:

```js
function axiosCallPost(url, datastr)
{
        axios.post(url, {
                data:datastr
                , responseType:'text'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
                        console.log("ok -> " + response.data);
                        return response.data;
        })
        /*
         * para simplificarme la vida, responde 'errorr'
         * pero debería devolver algo mas
         */
        .catch(function(response) {
                        console.log("ko -> " + response.data);
                        return 'errorr';
        });
}
```

Tanto dentro del `then` como del `catch`, el valor recibido es correcto. Sin embargo, en la función `validar_dni()` que llama a esta, el valor es siempre `[object Promise]`. Por qué?

```js
async function validar_dni(dni_a_validar, url, secc)
{
        var datastr = ('secc=' + secc + '&dni=' + dni_a_validar);
        const resultado = await axiosCallPost(url, datastr);
        return resultado;
}
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en tu código, la función `axiosCallPost` no esta retornando ningún valor, sino que recibe callbacks para manejar tanto los casos de éxito como de error. Sin embargo, para poder hacer `await` de la promise, necesitas también retornarla. Esto debería funcionar:

```
function axiosCallPost(url, datastr)
{
    return axios.post(url, {
            data:datastr
            , responseType:'text'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
                    console.log("ok -> " + response.data);
                    return response.data;
    })
    /*
     * para simplificarme la vida, responde 'errorr'
     * pero debería devolver algo mas
     */
    .catch(function(response) {
                    console.log("ko -> " + response.data);
                    return 'errorr';
    });
}
```

Recuerda que todas las funciones `async` necesitan que las llames con `await` para obtener el resultado (o leerlo en un `then`). De otra manera, solo obtendrás la `Promise`.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu propuesta. Me sigue sucediendo lo mismo. Dentro del `then` el valor es correcto pero fuera es incorrecto: siempre es un `[object Promise]`.

Comment: quieres decir que cuando haces esto `const resultado = await axiosCallPost(url, datastr);` resultado es un `[object Promise]`?

Comment: Si y el valor dentro del `then` se actualiza a los 2/3 segundos. No se supone que debe esperar el resultado?

Comment: Esto esta funcionando: https://repl.it/repls/SubtleHospitableMarketing e imprime el valor del resultado: "errorr"

Comment: Asegurate que al llamar a validar_dni también se este haciendo el manejo de la llamada (por ejemplo, con `await`).

Comment: Ahora mismo la llamo así: `const validacion_dni = validar_dni(dni, url_validacion, "dni");`

Comment: Vos decís que la llame así: `const validacion_dni = await validar_dni(dni, url_validacion, "dni");`?

Comment: ese es el problema, si es una llamada a una funcion `async`, debes llamarla con `await` o te devolvera una `Promise`.

Comment: Ajá! Voy a probar y vuelvo con el resultado.

Comment: Me da `syntaxerror` porque el `await` no está dentro de una función `async`

Comment: Si lo llamas desde una funcion, necesitas que esa funcion sea `async`. Otra manera es crear un bloque async y ejecutarlo inmediatamente, como en mi ejemplo del link.

Comment: Con el ejemplo del link, consigo un estado `fulfilled`de la `Promise`, pero la función `async()' sigue sin devolver el valor correcto. La modifiqué y la puse así: `return await axiosCallPost(url, datastr);`

Comment: no entiendo.. en el link se ve que el error es devuelto e impreso por consola, no se devuelve una promise. No puedo probar el caso positivo porque no tengo acceso a tu API, pero el resultado deberia ser el mismo.

Comment: Claro, dentro de la función `axiosCallPost` el resultado es correcto. Pero cuando hago `return response.data`, devuelve un objeto `Promise` en lugar del `string` de respuesta. Si la operación es correcta, devuelve 1, si no, devuelve el mensaje de texto y eso está bien. Solo que afuera de la llamada a axios no lo puedo ver porque si al `return` le aplico el `.data` siempre es `undefined` y no entiendo por qué.

Comment: Si utilizas una URL incorrecta, te devuelve el string de error?

Comment: si. lo acabo de verificar nuevamente.

Comment: Mira: https://ibb.co/CszXFT2

Answer (score 0):

Axios es una promesa, cuando usas then o catch estas resolviendo la promesa, por lo que estas retornando es una promesa resuelta que ya no contiente nada. Para poder retornar el valor que quieres tienes que resolver la promesa utilizando await y retornar el valor, en caso de un error retornar el error.

```
async function axiosCallPost(url, datastr) {

  try {

    const response = await axios.post(url, { data: datastr, responseType: 'text'});
    console.log("ok -> " + response.data);
    return response.data;

  } catch (err) {

    console.log("ko -> error");
    return 'errorr';
  }
}
```

Comment: async/await es solo otra manera de expresar lo que siempre se escribio con then/catch. El resultado de esa funcion deberia ser el mismo.

Comment: En realidad no, aqui yo resuelvo la promesa y despues retorno el valor. En los otros casos estan retornando la promesa ya resuelta.

Comment: No hay ningún problema en llamar al `then` de una "promesa ya resuelta", va a dar el valor de todas formas, sólo que inmediatamente. [Este artículo](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) sobre el *Promise chaining* es lectura obligatoria.

Comment: No entiendo por qué si `response.data` dentro de `axiosCallPost` es correcto, no devuelve ese valor. Leí el artículo de Promise Chaining, esclarecedor.

Comment: Pero probaste este código, funciono?

Comment: Si, lo probé, y me pasa lo mismo. Dentro de la llamada a axios, el resultado es correcto. Fuera es siempre un objeto. El código es literalmente el que puse. No hay nada mas.

Comment: Finalmente, he conseguido hacerlo funcionar: Modifiqué la función `validar()` para hacerla genérica aprovechando que le debía pasar el parámetro `sección`, y ahí metí la llamada a `axios`. Le paso un parámetro adicional que es el control del formulario para marcarlo en rojo o verde según haya validado o no. Me queda pendiente averiguar el motivo que dio pie a esta pregunta, pero será en otro momento. No sé ya cómo cerrar este tema. Gracias a todos por sus aportes. Este novato volverá en breve con mas dudas y mas lectura a cuestas.